# Does NASware 3.0 benefit a software RAID1 running Linux?

Tags: nas, raid-1, centos-7

WD Red drives comes with NASware 3.0 (or older ones NASware 2.0). In running a CentOS Linux server in RAID1, does NASware offer any benefit? Or is NASware a Microsoft server thing?

Comment: NASware is proprietary to Western Digital Red drives. It's features they implement for the disc itself. I don't think it has any OS restrictions. I have an answer about NASware. I'll find it and include a link to it

Comment: The question isn't whether or not one can use it with Linux.  The question is, is Linux able to better operate a software-RAID with a NASware drive.  For instance, does the Linux kernel become aware of any new operations, and make use of them?